# Game Recommendation for Hunger Games rip-off

Tags: game-recommendation, system-for-setting

I am wanting to run a campaign that is a rip-off of the Hunger Games (the arena death-match bit, not the deciding between two love interests or revolution aspects).

I'm looking for a set of game rules that meet the following criteria.

1. Has good, in depth rules around natural hazards; thirst, hunger, cold, sleep deprivation etc.
2. Both the natural hazards and injuries from combat should have in game effects that reduce your effectiveness before death occurs.
3. Some system of weapon proficiencies, where people are significantly better at a small number of weapons, and slightly better at weapons similar to that small number of weapons.
4. Medieval tech required. Bonus points if it also contains rules for modern/sci fi level tech.

The group mostly dislikes PvP, so I am intending to have this as last group surviving wins, with all the PCs in one group. There would then be the potential to form temporary alliances with NPC groups, which would start at a similar size.

Comment: How do you want the system to interact with multiple players at the table? Is this pure PvP, or do they operate as a group? If it's pure PvP, how much meta-information should there be?

Comment: I'm not making this an answer - cause I've not done it, but a lot of what you're asking for is in twilight 2000

Answer (score 0):

GURPS can be a nice choice to accomplish this. The rules of GURPS Basic Set are very detailed about these aspects of human body condition, natural hazards and the system is designed to be much similar to real life dynamics (physics, human limits, etc). The core stats, like ST, HT, DX and IQ works very well for survival settings, and the players cannot expect to kill a group of four or five enemies easily alone (more real combat).

The skills mechanics can fits very well on this kinda of campaign, since they explicit clearly the use and difficulties of using your skills, and how hard or easy is to learn them or use without training. In the fields of weapons skills, GURPS is very specific about what weapon you know how to use, and the favorite class of weapon narrow down it to be even more specific. You may consider to use GURPS Martial Arts if you want to a more complex set of rules for hand-to-hand combat.

The Basic Set alone covers basic aspects of Medieval scenarios, specially with its system of thrusting and swinging attacks. High Tech can be covered by the Basic Set as well, but you can expand it using the GURPS Ultra-Tech book.

A long time ago, I played a campaign of Resident Evil using GURPS. The aspect of survival was covered as the group os PCs were alone in a city infested with zombies, and should avoid being bitten, poisoned and look for food and shelter. They got tired because we got to stay awake in order to watch for zombies and run for survival. The Basic Set is in the Fourth Edition, but we had the Third Edition at that time.

Answer (score -3):

The Rolemaster system by Iron Crown ([a comparative overview of their systems is here](http://ironcrown.com/system-comparison/)) comes to mind - they tend to go for depth of detail.

Years ago, I played in a short campaign, partly set in a wilderness, using the Rolemaster system, and I consider it to have a high level of detail. Survival was important, although not the core focus of the adventure.

Comment: Have you had any experience recreating Hunger Games or a similar experience in Iron Crown? Our [game recommendation rules](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1070/1071#1071) strictly require that answers are backed up by experience. ("I've never tried it, but I'm sure this system could work" is explicitly not an acceptable type of answer.)

Comment: Also, even ignoring that requirement your answer needs some details about how this system meets the requirements given in the question. Currently all you've said is that it's a system with depth of detail.

Comment: @dopplegreener Years ago, I played in a short campaign, partly set in a wilderness, using the Rolemaster system, and I consider it to have a high level of detail. Survival was important, although not the core focus of the adventure.

Comment: @Grizzled Hi, I just wanted to explain why I'm still sticking with my -1 vote. Our standards for game-recommendation questions are really high, and require answers to show how they meet each of the individual criteria specified in the question. At the moment, your answer still doesn't really do this. Would it be possible for you to address each of the 4 criteria listed and explain how Rolemaster addresses them?

Comment: @Wibbs Since I'm not in possession of a set of Rolemaster books at the moment, I can't do more than point to the Arms Law expansion book for points 3 and 4. Thank you for your courtesy, however.